# Functional-analytic proof of the existence of non-symmetric random variables with vanishing odd moments

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, banach-spaces, geometric-probability, elementary-proofs

It is known that a random variable $X$ which is symmetric about $0$ (i.e $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution) must have all its odd moments (when they exist!) equal to zero. The converse is a strong temptation which has been around for perhaps a hundred years.

> **Question.** *Suppose $\mathbb E[X^n] = 0$ for all odd $n$. Is it true that $X$ is symmetric ?*

This question was solved in [Churchill (1946)](https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177730987). In fact, he proved something much stronger

> **Theorem**. *Let $X$ be a random variable and let $(a_m)_{m \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, the exists a random variable $Y$ such that (1) $\mathbb E[Y^{2m+1}] = a_m$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$, and (2) The Kolmogorov distance between $X$ and $Y$ is at most $\epsilon$.*

Of course this theorem immediately implies a negative answer to the above question.

The proof given in the paper is constructive, but somewhat mysterious.

> **Question.** *Is there simple / modern way to prove the above theorem using functional-analytic tools ?*

After all, the theorem simply says (roughly) that the set of random variables of with odd-moments given by the sequence $(a_m)$ is dense in the space of random variables equipped with Komolgorov distance.

**Note.** The expected advantage of a general functional-analytic solution is that it would perhaps extend to constraints which are more general than those implied by prescribed odd moments.

Comment: Any reason for the anonymous downvote ? A comment would be much more useful. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a sensible question to me.

Comment: And to me too...

Comment: Here is one: https://telescoper.wordpress.com/2018/07/09/the-problem-with-odd-moments/

Comment: The solution in your link is referring to the same Churchill-Stieltjes construction I discussed in the preface to my question...

Comment: @dohmatob That'll teach me about not clicking links... my bad.

Comment: The original question can also be answered with $X=Y-Z$, where $Y$ is lognormal and $Z$ is independent and has all moments equal to the moments of $Y$. The answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/3553/44143 has a formula for $Z$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This doesn't really require modern functional analytic tools, but we can prove a statement (due originally to Edelheit, according to Jochen Wengenroth in the comments) like

> Let $V$ be a Frechet space, complete with respect to a family of norms $||x||_i$, $i=0,1,\dots$. Let $L_1,L_2,\dots$ be linear forms on $V$, with $L_i$ bounded with respect to $||x||_i$ but unbounded with respect to any linear combination of $||x||_j$ for $j<i$. Then we can choose $x\in W$ with $L_i(x)$ arbitrary and $||x||_0$ arbitrarily small.

We can apply this by taking $V$ to be the completion of the space of smooth, compactly supported functions on $\mathbb R$ with respect to the set of norms $||f||_0 = \int |f(x)| dx$ and $||f||_m = \int |f(x)| |x|^{2m+1} dx$ for $m>0$, and $L_m(f) = \int f x^{2m+1} dx$. linear forms obtained by integrating against $x^{2n+1}$. This gives us a function $f(x)$ with desired odd moments and norm $\epsilon$, which we can make into a nonnegative function with the same moments and integral $\epsilon$ by the trick $g(x) =f^+(x) + f^-(-x)$. Then take $(1-\epsilon)$ of any measure plus $\epsilon$ times $g$ for suitable $g$.

To prove this: We fix a bunch of small constants $\epsilon_{ij}$, for $i,j \in \mathbb N$, to be chosen later.

After rescaling $L_1$, we may assume $|L_1(\cdot)| \leq ||\cdot||_1$.

Choose $x_1$ with $L_1(x_1)=1$ and $||x_1||_0 < \epsilon_{01}$ . Rescale  $||\cdot||_2$ and $L_2$ so that $||x_1||_2<\epsilon_{21}$ and $|L_2( \cdot) |\leq ||\cdot||_2$ and then find $x_2$ with $||x_2||_0 < \epsilon_{02}$, $||x_2||_1< \epsilon_{12}$, and $L_2(x_2)=1$. Rescale $||\cdot ||_3$ and $L_3$ so that $||x_1||_3<\epsilon_{31}$, $||x_2||_3<\epsilon_{32}$, and $L_3(\cdot) \leq ||\cdot||_3$, and iterate this process.

Let $M$ be the $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ matrix with entries $M_{ij} = L_i (x_j)$. We have $|M_{ij} |\leq \epsilon ij$ if $i \neq j$ and $1$ if $i=j$. Let $N = I + (I-M) + (I-M)^2 + (I-M)^3+ \dots $ be the inverse matrix, choosing $\epsilon_{ij}$ small enough that this sum converges. Taking $\epsilon_{ij}$ as small as we want, we can make the off-diagonal entries of $N$ as small as desired and the diagonal entries as close to $1$ as desired.

Then letting $$x =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} N_{ij} x_i a_j $$ we have $L_i(x) = a_i$ and $$ || x||_0 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |N_{ij}| ||x_i||_0 |a_j| \leq  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |N_{ij}| \epsilon_{0i}  |a_j|$$ which we can make as small as desired, and for any $k>0$

$$ || x||_k \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |N_{ij}| ||x_i||_k |a_j| \leq  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |N_{ij}| \epsilon_{ki}  |a_j|  +\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |N_{kj}| ||x_k||_k |a_j|$$, where the first term can be made as small as desired and the second term can, at least, be made convergent.

For example $\epsilon_{ij} = 2^{-i-j}/ (|a_j|+1)$ for $i \neq j$ and $\epsilon_{0i} = 2^{-i} \cdot \epsilon / (|a_i|+1)  $ will ensure $(N- I)_{ij}$ is bounded by $(3/2) 2^{-i -j} / (|a_j|+1)$ and so $||x||_0 = O(\epsilon)$ and $||x||_k = O ( \epsilon \cdot (1 + ||x_k||_k ) (1+ |a_k|) ) . $

The sign trick to make the function nonnegative is not strictly necessary. We can prove a similar statement like

> Let $f_1,f_2,\dots$ be functions on a measure space. Assume that  $$ \inf \frac{ f_i(x)}{1 + \sum_{j<i} |f_j(x)| } = - \infty $$ and $$ \sup \frac{ f_i(x)}{1 + \sum_{j<i} |f_j(x)| } = \infty. $$
> Then there exists a measure $\mu$ with $\int f_i \mu$ arbirarily and $\int \mu$ arbitarily small.

We just have to keep track of two measures $\mu_i^+, \mu_i^-$, with $\int f_i \mu_i^+=1$, $\int f_i \mu_i^-  =-1$, and the other integrals arbitrarily small.

Comment: Great piece of mathematics. Thanks (upvoted). Lemme try and parse it to be sure I follow everything in the constructions, then I'll accept it right away!

Comment: @ChristianRemling By suitable $g$ I mean one whose $2m+1$st moment is $a_m$ minus $1-\epsilon$ times the $2m+1$st moment of "any measure".

Comment: Small nitpick/request for clarification: when you say unbounded linear form on a Banach space I guess you mean a densely-defined linear map which is a closed operator, or something similar? To get discontinuous everywhere-defiined linear forms on a Banach space one needs something like the axiom of choice

Comment: @YemonChoi Good point - I was trying to use the convention that an unbounded linear operator need not be defined on the whole Banach space, but I need to assume that the operators are closed and something about the space of definition. I'm not sure if dense is enough because I need them all to be defined at some points. I'll revise...

Comment: @YemonChoi Actually this is a bit tricky. The linear forms in question are densely-defined, but not closed, and can't be made closed. In the example in question, the reason the linear form of an infinite sum matches the infinite sum of the linear form is some dominated convergence argument. I see a way to fix this but it's a little messy.

Comment: This general result about Fréchet spaces is called *Eidelheit theorem*. It is, e.g., in the book *Introduction to Functional Analysis* by Meise and Vogt.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Interesting - thanks for the reference! Since Eidelheit died tragically in 1943, this must predate Churchill's work, so indeed one doesn't need more modern techniques...