# Is it always possible to determine the distribution of a random variable given all its moments?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, moments

we we're asked about it, and I know that answer is "NO", and I haven't found an good enough answer yet
and would appreciate an explanation with examples.

Comment: Duplicate of : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3525/when-are-probability-distributions-completely-determined-by-their-moments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are probability distributions completely determined by their moments?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3525/when-are-probability-distributions-completely-determined-by-their-moments)

Answer (score 1):

An example, and a necessary and sufficient condition (in the case when the distribution is absolutely continuous) for the uniqueness, can be found e.g. [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1126095?journalCode=tprbau).